# Java - shift int enums

Tags: java, enums

In C, I sometimes used structures such as

```
enum {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;
```

Is there any Java equivalent?

Comment: Why? Is this just so you can handle sets of them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [EnumSet](http://dhruba.name/2008/12/31/effective-java-item-32-use-enumset-instead-of-bit-fields/).

**Excerpt** from the Link above which qualifies as example:

> ```
> package resolver;
>
> import java.util.EnumSet;
>
> public class EnumPatternExample {
>
>     public enum Style {
>         BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE, STRIKETHROUGH
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         final EnumSet<Style> styles = EnumSet.noneOf(Style.class);
>         styles.addAll(EnumSet.range(Style.BOLD, Style.STRIKETHROUGH)); // enable all constants
>         styles.removeAll(EnumSet.of(Style.UNDERLINE, Style.STRIKETHROUGH)); // disable a couple
>         assert EnumSet.of(Style.BOLD, Style.ITALIC).equals(styles); // check set contents are correct
>         System.out.println(styles);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need that binary logic with enums in java any more. You just need `enum` itself and `EnumSet`.

For example:

```
enum Color {
   Red, Green, Blue, Orange, White, Black
}

...

EnumSet<Color> mainColors = EnumSet.of(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue);
Color color = getSomeColor();
if (mainColors.contains(color)) {
   //mainColors is like Red | Green | Blue, 
   //and contains() is like color & mainColors
   System.out.println("Your color is either red or blue or green"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't really know what that C code does, but here's the closest you'll get to it in Java:

```
enum UIView {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 ( 0),
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   ( 1 << 0),
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        ( 1 << 1),
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  ( 1 << 2),
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    ( 1 << 3),
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       ( 1 << 4),
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin ( 1 << 5);
    private final int value;

    private UIView(int value){
        this.value = value;}

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
 };
```

Comment: you're right that it's the closest java version of the same program, but ideologically it's wrong. All those shifts are made for using binary logic with values (1, 2, 4, 8...) i.e. operators `|` and `&`. Java introduced `EnumSet` which makes things easier and allows to get rid of binary logic.

Comment: @Roman I agree totally. As I said, I don't even really understand this bit-shifting, it's a relic from ancient times. Java hides these details from me and I'm thankful. Still, my goal was to get the code to compile with as little modification as possible, and I guess I've accomplished that (even if it doesn't make much sense)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
enum EnumTest {
    ONE(1), //Specify value to pass to constructor
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3);

    private int num;

    private EnumTest(int num) { //Enum constructor must be private
        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getNum() { //Get the value specified on the constant's creation
        return num;
    }
}
```

You can then call getNum() on the enum to get the number you specified on the constant's creation. Enums are a lot more powerful and flexible in Java than in other languages generally - they were added a lot later but are essentially fully blown classes (and you can manipulate them as such.)

Answer (score 0):

Without addressing your shifting requirement you could do:

```
enum MyEnum {
       UIViewAutoresizingNone(0),
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin(1),
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth(2),
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin(3),
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin(4),
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight(5),
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin(6);

       private int value;

       private MyEnum(int value) {
           this.value = value;
       }

       public int getValue() {
           return value;
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you google "Java Enums" you can find examples on how to implement them. Basically in Java, Enums are like classes, they have constructors, methods, etc... And you can map values to the constant label, so your enum is easily converted to a Java enum.

```
public enum UIViewAutoresizingConstants
{
    UIViewAutoresizingNone(0),
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin(1 << 0);

    private int value;

    private UIViewAutoresizingConstants(int v)
    {
        this.value = v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.  You can define a Java enum and construct each enum type with your values:

```
public enum UIViewAutoresizing {
    None(0),
    FlexibleLeftMargin(1 << 0),
    FlexibleWidth(1 << 1),
    FlexibleRightMargin(1 << 2),
    FlexibleTopMargin(1 << 3),
    FlexibleHeight(1 << 4),
    FlexibleBottomMargin(1 << 5);

    private final int flag;

    private MessageType(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public int flag() {
        return flag;
    }
};
```

Then the method flag() will return your actual flag value.  Or better still you can define methods on your enums to do something useful depending on the value of the flag.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Emun items can't be assigned a value like that, you'd need something like:

```
public enum Classname {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone( 0 ),
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin ( 1 << 0 ),
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth( 1 << 1 ),
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin( 1 << 2 ),
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin( 1 << 3 ),
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight( 1 << 4),
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin( 1 << 5 ),

    private final double value;

    // constructor
    private Classname( double v ) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public double value()   { 
        return value; 
    }
 }
```

Then you would a value like this in your other code:

```
double x = Classname.UIViewAutoresizingNone.value;
```

This is asssuming you need to be able to access the value from other code and you weren't just adding it to make sure each enum value was different. For the latter case in Java you don't need to do this at all. For example, this will work:

```
public enum Classname {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth,
   ....
```